# list of urls in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

My string looks like this:

`http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Eddy-Need-Remix-mp3-image.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/static-pages.png`

How do I extract each urls in array like this:

```
array( 
  0 => 'http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpg' 

  1 => 'http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpg' 

  2 => 'http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpg' 
)
```

This is how i tried with no avail:

```
  $imgss = 'http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Eddy-Need-Remix-mp3-image.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/static-pages.png';

    preg_match_all(
        "#((?:[\w-]+://?|[\w\d]+[.])[^\s()<>]+[.](?:\([\w\d]+\)|(?:[^`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’\s]|(?:[:]\d+)?/?)+))#",
        $imgss
    ); 

    foreach($imgss as $imgs){
        echo '<img src="'.$imgs.'" />';
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. needless to say I am very weak in php

Thanks

Comment: since there's no delimiter, you can't explode the string in a traditional way; you're going to need to use a regex capture group, and explode the capture, and then put it back.

Comment: thanks. Can you post an example?

Comment: where are you getting the string from, I say because your be better off fixing how your getting the string instead of fixing after the fact. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: He can use explode and http:// though since these are unique characters related to the start of each string, and then add the missing http:// to the beginning of each element. That's the documentation of the explode function. http://au2.php.net/explode

Comment: @TheNavigator, i'm wondering if it will always be just `http` (and not sometimes `https`). If it's always http, `explode('http',$imgss);` and just manually add the `http` as part of the literal image tag: `'<img src"http'.$imgs.'" />'`

Comment: what will be the best way to store the urls in that string? the urls are inserted in a textarea through javascript. thanks

Comment: A. Don't store them as a string. B. Ensure there's a delimiter, like a whitespace character between each url.

Comment: I can do B. The string now looks like this: ` http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpg http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Eddy-Need-Remix-mp3-image.jpg http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/static-pages.png`
notice the space before each `http`

Comment: @jacob He may use "://" as a delimiter, or maybe "http". The point is, it's not perfect and it's vulnerable to errors. The perfect answer is using regex, and because even that may be vulnerable, you should follow Loz Cherone's advice. You should get the data as a valid JSON array (for example) instead.

Comment: If you have control over this entire process, the best way to do this would be to put the URLs into a Javascript array, JSON encode it and put it into your array as a hidden variable, and then submit.  On the PHP side, decode the JSON array into a PHP array.  That way there's no chance of messing up the values based on encode/decode discrepancies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no spaces in string you can use:

```
$string = 'http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Eddy-Need-Remix-mp3-image.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/static-pages.png';

$string = str_replace( 'http', ' http', $string );
$array = array_filter( explode( ' ', $string ) );


print_r( $array );
```

Answer (score 1):

Exploding is fine but perhaps you should also validate the inputted links, ive put together this which will let you know the inputted links need to be on a new line or have a space between them, then it will validate the links and create a new array of valid links that you can then do something with.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' & !empty($_POST['links'])){

    //replace all \r\n and \n and space with , delimiter
    $links = str_replace(array(PHP_EOL, "\r\n", " "), ',', $_POST['links']);

    //explode using ,
    $links = explode(',', $links);

    //validate links by going through the array
    foreach($links as $link){

        //does the link contain more then one http://
        if(substr_count($link, 'http://') >1){
            $error[] = 'Add each url on a new line or separate with a space.';
        }else{

            //does the link pass validation
            if(!filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
                $error[] = 'Invalid url skipping: '.htmlentities($link);
            }else{

                //does the link contain http or https
                $scheme = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
                if($scheme == 'http' || $scheme == 'https'){
                    //yes alls good, add to valid links array
                    $valid_links[] = $link;
                }else{
                    $error[] = 'Invalid url skipping: '.htmlentities($link);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    //show whats wrong
    if(!empty($error)){
        echo '
        <pre>
        '.print_r($error, true).'
        </pre>';
    }

    //your valid links do somthing
    if(!empty($valid_links)){
        echo '
        <pre>
        '.print_r($valid_links, true).'
        </pre>';
    }

}?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <textarea rows="2" name="links" cols="50"><?php echo (isset($_POST['links']) ? htmlentities($_POST['links']) : null);?></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$input = "http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Eddy-Need-Remix-mp3-image.jpghttp://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/static-pages.png";
$exploded = explode("http://", $input);

$result;
for ($i = 1; $i < count($exploded); ++$i)
{
    $result[$i - 1] = "http://" . $exploded[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, if you have control over this entire process.

Your form:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">

</form>
```

Your javascript (using jquery):

```
<script>

var myurls = getUrls();

$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'myurls',
    value: JSON.stringify(myurls),
}).appendTo('#myform');

// gathers your URLs (however you do this) and returns them as a javascript array
function getUrls() {

    // just return this as a placeholder/example
    return ["http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/46430454_Subscription_XXL-4_mini.jpg", "http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Eddy-Need-Remix-mp3-image.jpg", "http://localhost/layerthemes/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/static-pages.png"];
}

</script>
```

Your PHP:

```
$myurls = json_decode($_POST['myurls']);

var_dump($myurls); // should be the array you sent
```

You could do this with AJAX too if you want.  Or make the form automatically submit.